# How to retrieve a value from a particular column through cursor in android?

Tags: android

I am executing a query to select the maximum salary of an employee. The result is stored in the cursor. How can I get the value of the maximum(salary) from the cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below code .

```
cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("your field")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select MAX(SALARY) as BigSalary FROM Employee

cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("BigSalary"));
```